# mouse and keyboard presses are missed or slow in python window

Tags: python, python-2.7, psychopy

I'm afraid this issue might be too idiosyncratic but maybe someone can point me in the right direction via questions or hypotheses.

I'm using psychoPy 1.84.2 which uses python 2.7. The computers I am hoping to use for my study are dells running windows 10 enterprise.

The issue is that ~80% of the time mouse clicks are completely missed and keyboard presses take 3-4 seconds to have an effect in my program. 20% of the time, there is no issue. While this is happening, I can still see the mouse cursor moving and I can open up programs and folders on the desktop and click around the psychoPy GUI without any lag. Additionally, videos played in the python window run fine.

These same files run perfectly well on two different macs but fail on the 10 dell desktops I was hoping to use for my study. Lastly, I did try using psychoPy 1.85.1 but had the same issues (plus a couple more).

Thanks!

Comment: With this level of detail, this isn't going to be an answerable question here. Suggest you take this to the forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org where there can be a bit more to and fro discussion. But you would certainly need to provide much more information about what you are doing, with relevant code snippets.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Thanks! Here is a link to my post on the psychopy forum. I do have my own code but the shapes contains demo has the same issues as noted above.  [link](https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/mouse-not-working-in-psychopy-window/2747)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 enterprise can sometimes limit cpu bandwidth to certain programs at times.

Comment: thanks! I've tried changing the priority level for psychoPy but wasn't sure if that was an issue or not so I didn't pursue it much. I'll get our IT guy to use his administrative privilege to explore this possible issue.

Comment: Ok. Good luck! If I was helpful would you mind marking it as helpful so other people can see my answer?